# Predicate logic for words

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let $\Sigma$ be an Alphabet. $\Sigma^*$ the set of finite words over $\Sigma$. We define a signature $S=({*/2,\emptyset)}$. Let $M_{\Sigma}=(\Sigma^*,I)$ be a structure over this signature. Let $I(*) $ be the formal operator of concatenation. for example $ab*ba=abba$

$a)$Give a formula $A$ that represents  the empty String $\epsilon$ and uses a free variable $x$. Formally $M_{\Sigma}[A](\sigma)=1$   iff $\sigma(x)=\epsilon$

Here i said $\forall y(y*x=y)$

b)Give a formula $B$ with a free variable $y$ that has the meaning "length of 1" .Formally $M_{\Sigma}[B](\sigma)=1$   iff $\sigma(y)$has length 1

Here I said $\forall x \forall  y  (y=x*c) \to (\forall z((z*x=z) \lor (z*c=z))$

My idea was that a string of legnth one can only be concatenated by 2 strings if one of the strings is empty.

c)Let $\Sigma$ and $\Gamma$ be finite sets of letters with $|\Sigma| \gt |\Gamma| $. Give a Formula such that $M_{\Sigma}$ is fullfilled but $M_{\Gamma}$ is not.

Here i have not the sligthest Idea of what i could use. A tip would be nice.

Please can you take a look at my other answers too. And maybe there are easier solutions to it ?.

Thank you

Comment: signature $\ast/2 ,\emptyset$? You mean a binary operation $\ast$ and a constant (presumably $\varepsilon$)?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma * is a function that concatenates 2 strings and it takes 2 inputs and gives one output string . The empty set denotes that there are no predicates.

Comment: In part (b), the $\forall y$ is presumably $\forall c$.  In part (c), you need to use $|\Sigma|$ in your formula.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Ye you are right . Can you help me at part c) i still dont know how to do it

Comment: The idea for part (c) is that the formula distinguishes a specific $\Sigma$ from a specific (smaller) $\Gamma$.  The intuition is that with $\Sigma$ you have more distinct words of length one than with $\Gamma$.  In fact, you can have up to $|\Sigma|$ of them.  Is this enough of a hint?